# How to retrieve index of min value in array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on `kmeans` clustering algorithm, and I need to find the index of the smallest value in the array.

For example, I wrote this code for 3 item:

```
if ((DistanceArray[1, j] < DistanceArray[2, j]) && 
    (DistanceArray[1, j] < DistanceArray[3, j]))
{
    min= 1;
} 
else if (DistanceArray[2, j] < DistanceArray[3, j])
{
    min= 2;
}
else
{
    min= 3;
}
```

But I need to retrieve minimum value from a multidimensional array.

How can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each value and compare it to the current minimum. Declare min as float.MaxValue so any number except the max value for a float will be less than it.

```
float min = float.MaxValue; //set 'min' to the maximum value of a float
int minI, minJ;  //use if you want to track indices of the min value

for (int i = 0; i <= DistanceArray.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= DistanceArray.GetUpperBound(1); i++)
    {
        if (DistanceArray[i, j] <= min) //changed to '<= min' to which means if
        {                               //there are multiple minimum values the
            min = DistanceArray[i, j];  //one with the higher indices will be used
            minI = i;
            minJ = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you do `< (DistanceArray.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)` when you could just do `<= DistanceArray.GetUpperBound(0)`?

Comment: Don't initialize min so it's null ????? int is a value type,it cannot be null,it will have a default value 0

Comment: I wasn't sure which one would be clearer to OP. I guess `<=` would probably look better, huh? I'll edit it.

Comment: min isn't nullable in this context. Either make it int? min = null; or int min = int.Minvalue; and remove the null check in the inner loop.

Comment: I would avoid using null with min.  Just do `int min = Int32.MaxValue` and change `if (min == null || ...` to `if (...`

Comment: Richard Schneider --- what will happen if array its self contains Int32.MaxValue

Comment: @slash shogdhe The min value will still be Int32.MaxValue and thus correct; it's up to OP how he wants to implement multiple equal minimum values if he's keeping track of indexes.

Comment: my array is float and i can't use int min !

Comment: @slashm The only edge case is that all values in the array contain MaxValue.  In this, minI and minJ will not be set.  Change the `if` to use `<=`.

Comment: @Hadi, then use float.MaxValue.

Comment: Give @Matthew some upvotes for maintaining this snippet.

Comment: my array start from 1 not 0 i your code is not working

Comment: Why does your array start from 1? Regardless, you could just change the for loop to `int i = 1` and `int j = 1`...?

Comment: i used 0 for other and 1 and later for distance

Comment: @Matthew Mendez : your code is working properly in retrieve index of min value from all dimension of array , but i need to retrieve only "j" th column every analyze array !

Comment: You need to find the min value for every column in j? Is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,Here arr is two dimensional array

```
   int? minValue = null;
   var i = 0;
   var j = 0;
    foreach (var m in arr)
    {
      var min1 =   m.Min();
      if (minValue == null || minValue > min1)
      {
          minValue = min1;
          i = m.ToList().IndexOf(min1);
          j = arr.ToList().IndexOf(m);
      }

    }
```

Comment: yeah I know,but nested foreach is more extremely inefficient to me